# Is there a way of ignoring errors for assets on Vue build?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, eslint

I'm building a Vue project including some static files. For serving it locally, I've set this on `package.json`:

```json
{
  ...
  "eslintConfig": {
    ...
    "ignorePatterns": [
      "**/vendor/*.js"
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

and it works fine. But when I try to build it with `npm run build`, I get the following:

```
-  Building for production...
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /app/src/assets/vendor/fontawesome-free-5.15.3-web/js/all.min.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors

 error  in ./src/assets/vendor/bootstrap-4.6.0/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Module Error (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):

/app/src/assets/vendor/bootstrap-4.6.0/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
  6:144    error  'define' is not defined           no-undef
  6:157    error  'define' is not defined           no-undef
  6:234    error  'globalThis' is not defined       no-undef
  6:723    error  'a' is a function                 no-func-assign
  6:27968  error  Empty block statement             no-empty
  6:36778  error  Unnecessary escape character: \-  no-useless-escape
  6:37519  error  Unnecessary escape character: \-  no-useless-escape
  6:68065  error  'n' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars

✖ 8 problems (8 errors, 0 warnings)
```

The 2 errors are for these assets, both are similar. Is there a way of skipping these errors on build? It seems like a linting issue only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your config file includes this statement, you can try to commend out this line:

> ```
> "extends": "eslint:recommended"
> ```